# Error "Failed to load resource" when creating first mySQL, javascript, node project

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to create a simple contact manager project using html, javascript, node and MYSQL.

My database is created in MYSQL and I have a server.js node file which is up and running (when I run it with node it is running the app.listen console log.

Code here:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 5500;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'aaaaaaa',
    database: 'contactmanager',
    connectionLimit: 10
}); 

//define a route that retrieves data from the database and returns it as a JSON response
app.get('/data', (req,  res) => {
    //get a connection from the pool 
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
            return;
        }

        //execute a mySQL query
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM contactmanager.contacts', (error, results) => {
            //release the connection back to the pool
            connection.release();

            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
                return;
            }

            //send the results as a JSON response
            res.json(results);
        });
    });
});

//start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

My package.json file looks as follows:

```
{
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

my scripts.js file is throwing up this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn7n8.jpg).
my scripts file starts as follows, line 14 (with the apparent issue) is the .catch line :

```
fetch('/data')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Update the form elements with the retrieved data
    document.querySelector(".firstname").value = data.firstname;
    document.querySelector(".surname").value = data.surname;
    document.querySelector(".phone").value = data.phone;
    document.querySelector(".email").value = data.email;
    document.querySelector(".firstline").value = data.firstline;
    document.querySelector(".town").value = data.town;
    document.querySelector(".county").value = data.county;
    document.querySelector(".postcode").value = data.postcode;
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error, response));
```

I'm a beginner and so this is my first project using mysql and node, therefore I've tried googling and using chatGPT to guide me through, but neither have been able to solve my issue.

If I'm missing any info please let me know and I'll give you everything necessary.

Comment: Can you post the code on your server where the /data endpoint is accessed?

Comment: I've added the code for that file above. Thank you.